# Link error for masm. LNK2001: unresolved external symbol. Assembly language

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I successfully assembled the following code buy I cannot link it.

```
 TITLE Add and Subtract

;This program adds and subtracts 32-bit integers

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.code
main PROC 

mov eax,10000h
add eax,40000h
sub eax,20000h
call DumpRegs

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

I'm using the following command to link it.

link addsub.obj irvine32.lib kernel32.lib /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /DEBUG

I'm getting the followng error.

irvine32.lib : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MessageBoxA@16
addsub.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I do not know where to find this MessageBox and link it to the program.  Any help?

edit:

So I linked User32.lib into the file with the following command.

link addsub.obj irvine32.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /DEBUG

and got the following error.

LINK: fatal error LNK1000: unknown error consult documentation for technical support options.

What am I supposed to do with that?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx Library
User32.lib

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/902497).

Comment: Can you show us the command you use to assemble addsub?

Answer (score -2):

> I do not know where to find this MessageBox and link it to the program. Any help?

I [read the fine manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) for you:

> ## MessageBox function
>
> **Library** User32.lib

Comment: I added this comment to original post because of bad formatting here.  See original post for this comment

Comment: It's a different problem so ask another question. On Stack Overflow you're allowed one question per question. I did some light Googling for you and it seems like at least one instance of this problem occurs when trying to mix-and-match object files with different levels of optimisations. I take it you're using http://www.kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2012/index.htm so I'd recommend looking at the batch files and making sure that what you're trying to do is the same as what they're doing.